# How to test whether a sequence of sections have gaps in it?

Tags: r

I have several (ice-)core section samples in a dataset (`ID` in the example below). Some cores have missing sections (i.e. gaps), but I do not know which ones. How to find this out using R?

Example:

```
dt <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Sec.start = c(0, 
5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 0, 5, 10, 30), Sec.end = c(5, 10, 20, 
30, 100, 200, 400, 5, 10, 20, 50), Section = c("0-5", "5-10", 
"10-20", "20-30", "50-100", "100-200", "200-400", "0-5", "5-10", 
"10-20", "30-50")), .Names = c("ID", "Sec.start", "Sec.end", 
"Section"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

dt

    ID Sec.start Sec.end Section
1   a         0       5     0-5
2   a         5      10    5-10
3   a        10      20   10-20
4   a        20      30   20-30
5   b        50     100  50-100
6   b       100     200 100-200
7   b       200     400 200-400
8   c         0       5     0-5
9   c         5      10    5-10
10  c        10      20   10-20
11  c        30      50   30-50
```

"a" and "b" do not have gaps, whereas "c" does (missing piece between 20 and 30), so I am after a following result:

```
$a
[1] TRUE

$b
[1] TRUE

$c
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
lapply(split(dt,dt$ID),function(x) all(x[-1,2]==x[-nrow(x),3]))
#$a
#[1] TRUE
#$b
#[1] TRUE
#$c
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Grande Nicola, as always ;)

Comment: Lol :), nice to see you after a long time @SabDeM!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(check = all(Sec.end == lead(Sec.start, default = last(Sec.end))))
#Source: local data table [3 x 2]
#
#      ID check
#  (fctr) (lgl)
#1      a  TRUE
#2      b  TRUE
#3      c FALSE
```

Or the same using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .(check = all(Sec.end == shift(Sec.start, 1L, 'lead', fill = last(Sec.end)))), 
               by=ID]
#   ID check
#1:  a  TRUE
#2:  b  TRUE
#3:  c FALSE
```

Both approaches make use of lag/lead functions (in data.table called `shift`) to compare each `Sec.end` value to the next row's `Sec.start` value. In the last row, where there's no leading `Sec.start` value, we supply a default value which is the last row's `Sec.end` - this means the last row (per ID) is always `TRUE`. We use `all` to check if all of the comparisons are `TRUE` per ID.

Comment: Both solutions (the accepted and this) solve the problem. I accepted @nicola's solution, because it does not require any extra packages. Thank you for a good answer!